# Check Box selected is displayed wrongly

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am working on a screen where i am populating a list view using base adapter.Each row of list view contains a circular image view,Text View and Check box .On clicking single tick on toolbar ,i am displaying the id of user corresponding to checked button But it is displayed wrongly.I am implementing the following screen:

[image: Screenshot]

**1.Bean_Friends**

```
    public class Bean_Friends {
    private String name, url, extension, friendsID;
    private String friendSelected = "false";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getExtension() {
        return extension;
    }

    public void setExtension(String extension) {
        this.extension = extension;
    }

    public String getFriendsID() {
        return friendsID;
    }

    public void setFriendsID(String friendsID) {
        this.friendsID = friendsID;
    }

    public String getFriendSelected() {
        return friendSelected;
    }

    public void setFriendSelected(String friendSelected) {
        this.friendSelected = friendSelected;
    }
}
```

**2.Adapter_Friends_Group.java**

```
    public class Adapter_Friends_Group extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    public List<Bean_Friends> listBeanFriends;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ApiConfiguration apiConfiguration;
    private Bean_Friends bean_friends;


    public Adapter_Friends_Group(Context context, List<Bean_Friends> listBeanFriends) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listBeanFriends = listBeanFriends;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listBeanFriends.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return listBeanFriends.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (inflater == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item_friends, null);
        }

        //finding different views
        ImageView pic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.friendsImage);
        TextView txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameFriends);
        CheckBox chkFriends = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkFriends);

        bean_friends = listBeanFriends.get(i);
        String name = bean_friends.getName();
        String url = bean_friends.getUrl();
        String extension = bean_friends.getExtension();
        apiConfiguration = new ApiConfiguration();
        String api = apiConfiguration.getApi();
        String absolute_url = api + "/" + url + "." + extension;

        //loading image into ImageView                                                                                                                                            iew
        Picasso.with(context).load(absolute_url).error(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(pic);

        //Setting name in the textview
        txtName.setText(name);

        //If check box is checked,then add true to bean else add false to bean
        if (chkFriends.isChecked()) {
            bean_friends.setFriendSelected("true");
        } else {
            bean_friends.setFriendSelected("false");
        }


        chkFriends.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;
                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                    bean_friends.setFriendSelected("true");
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Check Box is checked : " + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    bean_friends.setFriendSelected("false");
                }
            }
        });


        return view;
    }
}
```

**3. Code of Activity containing view**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_new_group, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.createGroup:
            createNewGroup();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


public void createNewGroup() {
    Toast.makeText(NewGroupActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    List<Bean_Friends> listBeanFriends = new ArrayList<>();
    //Log.e("Size of listbeanFriends", String.valueOf(listBeanFriends.size()));

    listBeanFriends = adapter_friends_group.listBeanFriends;
    //  Log.e("Size of adapter_friends", String.valueOf(adapter_friends_group.listBeanFriends.size()));
    Log.e("Size of listbeanFriends", String.valueOf(listBeanFriends.size()));
    for (int i = 0; i < listBeanFriends.size(); i++) {
        Log.e("Loop Working", String.valueOf(i));
        Bean_Friends bean_friends = listBeanFriends.get(i);
        String friendID = bean_friends.getFriendsID();
        String friendSelected = bean_friends.getFriendSelected();
        String friendName = bean_friends.getName();
        Log.e("FriendsName", friendName);
        Log.e("FriendID", friendID);
        Log.e("friendSelected", friendSelected);
        if (friendSelected.equals("true")) {
            Toast.makeText(NewGroupActivity.this, friendID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            // Toast.makeText(NewGroupActivity.this,"true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated code:**

Solved the issue after doing the following changes:

**Adapter**

```
    public class Adapter_Friends_Group extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    public List<Bean_Friends> listBeanFriends;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ApiConfiguration apiConfiguration;
    private Bean_Friends bean_friends;


    public Adapter_Friends_Group(Context context, List<Bean_Friends> listBeanFriends) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listBeanFriends = listBeanFriends;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtName;
        CheckBox chkFriend;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listBeanFriends.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return listBeanFriends.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (inflater == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item_friends, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.friendsImage);
            viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameFriends);
            viewHolder.chkFriend = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkFriends);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        bean_friends = listBeanFriends.get(i);
        String name = bean_friends.getName();
        String url = bean_friends.getUrl();
        String extension = bean_friends.getExtension();
        apiConfiguration = new ApiConfiguration();
        String api = apiConfiguration.getApi();
        String absolute_url = api + "/" + url + "." + extension;

        //loading image into ImageView                                                                                                                                            iew
        Picasso.with(context).load(absolute_url).error(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(viewHolder.imageView);
        //Setting name in the textview
        viewHolder.txtName.setText(name);
        //Setting boolean isSelected if the Checkbox is checked
        viewHolder.chkFriend.setChecked(bean_friends.isSelected());
        viewHolder.chkFriend.setTag(bean_friends);


        viewHolder.chkFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;
                Bean_Friends bean_friends = (Bean_Friends) cb.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked on Checkbox: " + bean_friends.getName() + " is " + cb.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                bean_friends.setIsSelected(cb.isChecked());
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Bean**

```
    public class Bean_Friends {
    private String name, url, extension, friendsID;
    boolean isSelected;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getExtension() {
        return extension;
    }

    public void setExtension(String extension) {
        this.extension = extension;
    }

    public String getFriendsID() {
        return friendsID;
    }

    public void setFriendsID(String friendsID) {
        this.friendsID = friendsID;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setIsSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }
}
```

**Method inside Activity**

```
 public void createNewGroup() {
    StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
    listBeanFriends = adapter_friends_group.listBeanFriends;
    //  Log.e("Size of adapter_friends", String.valueOf(adapter_friends_group.listBeanFriends.size()));
    Log.e("Size of listbeanFriends", String.valueOf(listBeanFriends.size()));
    for (int i = 0; i < listBeanFriends.size(); i++) {
        Log.e("Loop Working", String.valueOf(i));
        Bean_Friends bean_friends = listBeanFriends.get(i);
        String friendID = bean_friends.getFriendsID();
        String friendName = bean_friends.getName();
        Log.e("FriendsName", friendName);
        Log.e("FriendID", friendID);
        Log.e("FriendSelected", String.valueOf(bean_friends.isSelected()));
        if (bean_friends.isSelected()) {
            responseText.append("\n" + bean_friends.getName() + "  " + bean_friends.getFriendsID());
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(NewGroupActivity.this, responseText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: What defines wrongly? In the wrong position, not the circular, checked when you expected it checked or unchecked when you expected checked?

Comment: For example ,When i checked a check box  corresponding to person A,it is displaying the ID of person C .I think i am doing some mistake inside adapter.

Answer (score 2):

I think the mistake is in this line :-

```
//If check box is checked,then add true to bean else add false to bean
if (chkFriends.isChecked()) {
    bean_friends.setFriendSelected("true");
} else {
    bean_friends.setFriendSelected("false");
}
```

Here you are setting 'setFriendSelected' based on whether the chkFriends is checked or not. In list View the views are reused and if say you have checked 'A' as friend and then you scrolls down then the view of 'A' maybe reused in 'C' and by this code 'C' now  will be checked as friend. Here you instead want to inflate your checkBox view according to whether 'C' is your friend or not. Try this instead:-

```
//If check box is checked,then add true to bean else add false to bean
    if (bean_friends.getFriendSelected().equals("true")) {
        chkFriends.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        chkFriends.setChecked(false);
    }
```

P.S : you can use view holder pattern here for better performance.